# Execution Within SQL Server Agent vs Package Execution Utility

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

**Simple question:** how does the execution of a ssis package differ when using the SQL Server 2012 Integration Package Utility versus when using the 2012 SQL Server Agent to execute a package? (**holding all else constant within deployment**- ie using the local file system in both cases)

Thank you.

---

I am asking because I have an externally referenced dll in my ssis package script that successfully executes with the package utility but not when deployed to the server agent within SQL server 2012 mgmt studio.

Comment: Is your job configured to use the "SQL Server Agent Service Account" (default) and has it access to the reference dll?

Comment: @MWillemse The accounts are the same in both instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the agent service is running on an account that has proper permissions, check to ensure that you are executing the same runtime version for both instances.  Your driver may be 64 bit and incompatible with 32 bit runtime and vice-versa.

There is an option in "execution options" of the agent job step that will allow you to select the 32 bit runtime, if needed.

If you are unable to get the "SQL Server Integration Services Package" job step type to work, you can change to using the "Operating system (CmdExec)" job step type and simply build a command using the utility executable (dtexec) and copying the info from the "Command line" tab of the utility.  Some prefer this method of executing SSIS packages with the agent as it provides cleaner maintenance of the jobs. Searching the google for this topic will bring up articles like this: http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2008/06/ssis-and-sql-server-agent-choosing.html

Hope this helps.